# Kudan 3D Object Recognition

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, object-recognition, kudan

I am trying to get into the Kudan AR framework (in Unity) and I have seen this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZ_iRinEnDE) of 3D Object Recognition. Now I am wondering how this is possible with that framework. I have also seen [another example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdSv7eUmFEk) where it is explicitly about to regocnize one of the 6 sides of the box (to overlay the model of the car), but if I understand that correct the first one is really about to recognize the real object itself and not the sides (So I would at least understand the title and the video).

Maybe someone can help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's probably just tracking multiple image markers to get the right position and orientation to give to the model. If the user turns the box, it starts tracking the side instead of the front.

Comment: It seemed that it is not a cube recognition in the video. I am not sure kudan, but vuforia, the cube recognition is just 6 pictures recognition.